# Check key Backspace

Tags: c

How can I check the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key? I tried this:

```
char ch = getchar();
 while (ch != 'x')
 {
  ch = getchar();
  if (ch == 0x08)
  {
       printf("BS");
  }
 }
```

but it does not work, any suggestions?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If stdin is line-buffered then you'll never see the keypresses, only the final result. The exact method for disabling line-buffering can be found in other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `<conio.h>` there is a `getch()` method which can catch that key, but it does not echo it IIRC, it's been a long time since faffing around with those... the neat thing about using that function, it is portable in the sense that under Unix and curses, there's an exact same function that does the same thing...

Comment: i`m using linux, can i use curses.h??

Comment: @jjreina: **YOU** should have explicitly stated that you are using linux in your question.... enough of us guessing...